# How do i verify Oracle 11g standby database is updating

Tags: database, oracle-11g

We have recently set up a DR site for our Oracle 11g database server at a remote location as a standby database.

How do I verify that the archive logs are being applied to the standby database and what is the last one thats been applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these links from the 11g Data Guard Concepts and Administration (you don't need Data Guard to be configured for these to be useful):

[3.2.7 Verify the Physical Standby Database Is Performing Properly](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/create_ps.htm#i77231) or [4.2.6 Verify the Logical Standby Database Is Performing Properly](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/create_ls.htm#i70028).

If you have Grid Control, it's even easier. There's a link under Maintenance that allows you to maintain your Data Guard configuration, including a graphical display of transport and apply lag times, last log received/applied, and other goodies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query on the Primary database

```
select max(sequence) from V$archived_log;
```

and on the standby database

```
select max(sequence) from V$log_history;
```

If the result is same it means your standby database is in sync with the primary database.